# SQL WHERE ... IN clause with possibly null parameter

Tags: sql, where-clause, conditional-statements

I am having some problems with my WHERE clause (using SQL 2008) .  I have to create a stored procedure that returns a list of results based on 7 parameters, some of which may be null.  The ones which are problematic are @elements, @categories and @edu_id.  They can be a list of ids, or they can be null.  You can see in my where clause that my particular code works if the parameters are not null.  I'm not sure how to code the sql if they are null.  The fields are INT in the database.

I hope my question is clear enough.  Here is my query below.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @elements nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @jobtype_id INT
DECLARE @edu_id nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @categories nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @full_part bit
DECLARE @in_demand bit
DECLARE @lang char(2)

SET @jobtype_id = null
SET @lang = 'en'
SET @full_part = null -- full = 1, part = 0
SET @elements = '1,2,3'
SET @categories = '1,2,3'
SET @edu_id = '3,4,5'

select 
jobs.name_en,
parttime.fulltime_only,
jc.cat_id category,
je.element_id elem,
jt.name_en jobtype,
jobs.edu_id minEdu,
education.name_en edu
from jobs
left join job_categories jc
on (jobs.job_id = jc.job_id)
left join job_elements je
on (jobs.job_id = je.job_id)
left join job_type jt
on (jobs.jobtype_id = jt.jobtype_id)
left join education
on (jobs.edu_id = education.edu_id)
left join 
(select job_id, case when (jobs.parttime_en IS NULL OR jobs.parttime_en = '') then 1 else 0 end fulltime_only from jobs) as parttime
on jobs.job_id = parttime.job_id
where [disabled] = 0    
and jobs.jobtype_id = isnull(@jobtype_id,jobs.jobtype_id)
and fulltime_only = isnull(@full_part,fulltime_only)
-- each of the following clauses should be validated to see if the parameter is null
-- if it is, the clause should not be used, or the SELECT * FROM ListToInt... should be replaced by 
-- the field evaluated: ie if @elements is null, je.element_id in (je.element_id)
and je.element_id IN (SELECT * FROM ListToInt(@elements,','))
and jc.cat_id IN (SELECT * FROM ListToInt(@categories,','))
and education.edu_id IN (SELECT * FROM ListToInt(@edu_id,','))

order by case when @lang='fr' then jobs.name_fr else jobs.name_en end;  

END
```

Comment: `WHERE .. @X IS NULL OR @X = COL ..` - the query planner will sort it all out.

Comment: @user2246674 - Not without `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` it doesn't (performance wise)

Comment: @MartinSmith Ahh, yes, a good point - that can affect the plan and change the joins used. But won't the constants still be folded without a recompile?

Comment: @user2246674 - The definitive article on the topic is [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL
Version for SQL 2008](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
and (@elements IS NULL OR je.element_id IN 
(SELECT * FROM ListToInt(@elements,',')))
and (@categories IS NULL OR 
jc.cat_id IN (SELECT * FROM ListToInt(@categories,',')))
....
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
je.element_id IN (SELECT * FROM ListToInt(@elements,',')) OR @elements IS NULL
```

that way for each one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly comparing to NULL?

```
and (@elements is null or je.element_id IN (SELECT * FROM ListToInt(@elements,','))
```

And so on.